# Django - creating automatically database in postgresql for tests, and deleting it after it

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I wonder if there is a possibility to trigger somehow automatic creation of database directly from application's code, only for tests purpose. In the perfect scenario, it should look like:

1. Run the tests in Django
2. Database being automatically created and fulfilled (postgresql)
3. After tests pass, whole database should be deleted.

For now what I have, is only fulfilling database with tables, and dropping it after tests, but I can't figure out if there is a possibility to trigger creation of database, so user won't be force to do it manually. I was looking for solution, but couldn't find any proper answer for it.

I was trying to find a solution for it in documentation in Django, or postgresql but couldn't find any similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tests that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your “real” (production) database. Separate, blank databases are created for the tests.

Regardless of whether the tests pass or fail, the test databases are destroyed when all the tests have been executed.

You can specify test database in `settings.py`. See [Test Database Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database).

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'TEST': {
        'NAME': 'mytestdatabase',
    },
},
}
```